# How do I get my ability.rb to work properly for my index action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, cancan, cancancan

This is what my `ability.rb` looks like:

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    user ||= User.new # guest user (not logged in)
    if user.has_role? :admin
      can :manage, :all
    end

    can :manage, Connection, inviter_user_id: user.id

  end
end
```

In my controller I have this:

```
class ConnectionsController < ApplicationController
  load_and_authorize_resource
  skip_authorize_resource only: :index

  layout 'connections'

  def index
     @family_tree = current_user.family_tree
     @inviter_connections = current_user.inviter_connections.order("updated_at desc")
     @invited_connections = current_user.invited_connections.order("updated_at desc")
  end
end
```

In my `application_controller.rb`, I have this:

```
  rescue_from CanCan::AccessDenied do |exception|
    redirect_to authenticated_root_url, :alert => exception.message
  end
```

Yet, when I try to visit `/connections` when I am not logged in, I get this error:

```
NoMethodError at /connections
undefined method `family_tree' for nil:NilClass
```

Also, when I remove the `can :manage, Connection` from my `ability.rb` it actually sends me to my login page like I expect.

How do I get both to work?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are using Devise for authentication. For this kind of validation when using devise you should add this to your controller:

```
before_action :authenticate_user!
```

Comment: Ok this got me to another error, which is `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound at /users/login
Couldn't find User with 'id'=login` How do I customize the route that this redirects me to? It is sending the request to `/users/login` and I want it to send it to `login_path`. How do I achieve that?

Comment: I believe its better to use the default devise paths for login, but you can achieve what you want following these instructions: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Redirect-to-a-specific-page-when-the-user-can-not-be-authenticated

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    user ||= User.new # guest user (not logged in)

    if user.has_role? :admin
      can :manage, :all
    else
      can :manage, Connection, inviter_user_id: user.id
    end

  end
end
```

Also, noticed that you are skip_authorize_resource only: :index, try commenting out that and see if it works.

Comment: Nope. No such luck :(

Comment: Commenting out `skip_authorize_resource` doesn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

On line 8 of your controller, `current_user` is nil when you're not logged in, and it's calling `family_tree` on it.

You need something like (just as an example, it depends on your needs):

```
 @family_tree = current_user.try(:family_tree) || FamilyTree.new
```

The reason it "works" when you remove the line in `Ability` is because that removes the ability to see the connection, so the `before_filter` redirects before you ever get inside `index`. What's probably tripping you up is the `Connection` record has a `inviter_user_id` of `nil`, and `User#id` is `nil`, so it's giving you permission to get into `index`.

Comment: Yeh I know this is the reason for the issue. The question is how do I get CanCanCan to help to fix it. If the user is not logged in, they should not be able to view the `Connection#Index` resource at `/connections` at all. So I don't want to create a new object for any of my models on that page, depending on if the user is a current_user. I just want to redirect them to the appropriate login page. But, when they are already logged in, I want to make sure they can only access the `Connection#Index` that relates to them. How do I achieve both?

Comment: Is there a `Connection` in your database with `inviter_user_id` of nil?

Comment: Nope. `[9] pry(main)> Connection.where(inviter_user_id: nil)
  Connection Load (0.9ms)  SELECT "connections".* FROM "connections"  WHERE "connections"."inviter_user_id" IS NULL
=> []`

Answer (score 0):

It could also happen if you forgot to put this at the top of the controller:

```
load_and_authorize_resource
```

See [docs](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan#controller-helpers) for more.